# Excel 2010 VBA Referencing Specific Cells in other worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sorry this is probably an extremely basic `Excel VBA` question.  I've just started learning it, and I am not finding very much in the way of good tutorials.  I can't find much organised information on the language at all actually.

I've got a couple worksheets called "Sheet1" and "Sheet2".
The first and second columns of Sheet1 contain some numbers.

I want to write a macro which prints the results of a function taking 2 variables (one each from column A and column B) to Sheet2.  but I want to space these results out in the new work sheet so that the result of the function on Column 'i' in Sheet1 is put into row 1 and column 4*i.  Here's what I've tried to do so far, but it hasn't worked because I don't know how to reference specific cells in other worksheets properly.

Apologies that this is a very newb question, any help is much appreciated!

```
Sub results()

    Dim i As Integer, noValues As Integer
    noValues = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    For i = 1 To noValues
        Range("A1").Offset(0, 4 * (i - 1)).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!A[i] + Sheet1!B[i]"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Where A[i] and B[i] should mean the value in Column A or B, row i.

Comment: Just a general tip for Excel. You almost NEVER need to "Select" or "Activate" a cell, sheet, or anything. In your example you can just say Range("A1").Offset(0,4 * (i-1)).formulaR1C1 = "Your Formula" all the other stuff is redundant and slows down your code ALOT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Sub Results2()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim shSource As Worksheet
    Dim shDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCnt As Long

    Set shSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    For Each rCell In shSource.Range("A1", shSource.Cells(shSource.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Cells
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        shDest.Range("A4").Offset(0, lCnt * 4).Formula = "=" & rCell.Address(False, False, , True) & "+" & rCell.Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False, , True)
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

This loops through column A of sheet1 and creates a formula in sheet2 for every cell.  To find the last cell in Sheet1, I start at the bottom (shSource.Rows.Count) and .End(xlUp) to get the last cell in the column that's not blank.

To create the elements of the formula, I use the Address property of the cell on Sheet.  I'm using three of the arguments to Address.  The first two are RowAbsolute and ColumnAbsolute, both set to false.  I don't care about the third argument, but I set the fourth argument (External) to True so that it includes the sheet name.

I prefer to go from Source to Destination rather than the other way.  But that's just a personal preference.  If you want to work from the destination,

```
Sub Results3()

    Dim i As Long, lCnt As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    lCnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1))
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Const sSOURCE As String = "Sheet1!"

    For i = 1 To lCnt
        sh.Range("A1").Offset(0, 4 * (i - 1)).Formula = "=" & sSOURCE & "A" & i & " + " & sSOURCE & "B" & i
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks!  I'm surprised there's no trivial way to loop through columns.  I'm finding vba less intuitive than c++ or python, and it's meant to be easier isn't it?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I am going to give you a simplistic answer that hopefully will help you with VBA in general.  The easiest way to learn how VBA works and how to reference and access elements is to record your macro then edit it in the VBA editor.  This is how I learned VBA.  It is based on visual basic so all the programming conventions of VB apply. Recording the macro lets you see how to access and do things.

you could use something like this:

```
var result = 0
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
result = Range("A1").Value * Range("B1").Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("D1").Value = result
```

Alternatively you can also reference a cell using `Cells(1,1).Value` This way you can set variables and increment them as you wish.  I think I am just not clear on exactly what you are trying to do but i hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this, but all I get when I record a macro are relative cell references.  So if I want a value from another cell, the VBA recording just says something along the lines of "Take the cell 4 rows left and 17 columns down" as opposed to "Take the cell in B20".

Comment: @Derek did you choose absolute or relative referencing when you recorded your macro?

Comment: Good point.  But that still doesn't help me with running things like for loops.  Lets say I have a known number of columns all of arbitrary length.  How would I write a macro which printed the length of every column at the end of the column?  (I mean length to be the number of non-empty cells in a column).

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Click_Click()

 Dim vaFiles As Variant
 Dim i As Long

For j = 1 To 2
vaFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename _
     (FileFilter:="Excel Filer (*.xlsx),*.xlsx", _
     Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsArray(vaFiles) Then Exit Sub

 With Application
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  For i = 1 To UBound(vaFiles)
     Workbooks.Open vaFiles(i)
     wrkbk_name = vaFiles(i)
    Next i
  .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

If j = 1 Then
work1 = Right(wrkbk_name, Len(wrkbk_name) - InStrRev(wrkbk_name, "\"))
Else: work2 = Right(wrkbk_name, Len(wrkbk_name) - InStrRev(wrkbk_name, "\"))
End If



Next j

'Filling the values of the group name

'check = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(Name, work1)
check = InStr(UCase("Qoute Request"), work1)

If check = 1 Then
Application.Workbooks(work1).Activate
Else
Application.Workbooks(work2).Activate
End If

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("GI Quote Request").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("B4:C12").Copy
Application.Workbooks("Model").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Request").Range("K3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


Application.Workbooks("Model").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Request").Select

Range("D3").Value = Range("L3").Value
Range("D7").Value = Range("L9").Value
Range("D11").Value = Range("L7").Value

For i = 4 To 5

If i = 5 Then
GoTo NextIteration
End If

If Left(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value, Len(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value) - 1) = Range("K" & i).Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i).Value = Range("L" & i).Value
 End If

NextIteration:
Next i

'eligibles part
Count = Range("D11").Value
For i = 27 To Count + 24
Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Insert
Next i

check = Left(work1, InStrRev(work1, ".") - 1)

'check = InStr("Census", work1)
If check = "Census" Then
workbk = work1
Application.Workbooks(work1).Activate
Else
Application.Workbooks(work2).Activate
workbk = work2
End If

'DOB
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

Application.Workbooks("Model").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Request").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("C27").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Gender
Application.Workbooks(workbk).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

Application.Workbooks("Model").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Request").Select
'Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveSheet.Range("k27").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

For i = 27 To Count + 27
ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value = Left(ActiveSheet.Range("k" & i).Value, 1)
Next i

'Salary
Application.Workbooks(workbk).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("N2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

Application.Workbooks("Model").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Request").Select
'Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveSheet.Range("F27").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


ActiveSheet.Range("K3:L" & Count).Select
selction.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe some explanational text would be nice to improve your answer.